# In Gunicorn, how can I add Connection: Close to the response once server shutdown has begun?

Tags: http, nginx, wsgi, gunicorn

I'm aware of the `on_exit` hook in Gunicorn, but not sure how or whether this can be used to add a "Connection: Close" HTTP header to the final response(s).

The reason I need this is to inform an upstream Nginx proxy of the shutdown, because otherwise Nginx gives "502 Bad Gateway" errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gunicorn provides worker hooks which can be used in this instance to send the Connection: close header when the workers are shutting down. Try the following hook in your `gunicorn.conf` file:

```
def pre_request(worker, req):

    if not worker.alive:
        header_dict = dict(req.headers)
        header_dict['CONNECTION'] = 'close'
        req.headers = header_dict.items()
```

Gunicorn stores the headers as a list of tuples, so was simpler to convert into a dictonary, overwrite/insert the CONNECTION header and place back into the object as list of tuples once done.